# Custom Adapter cannot be referenced from a static context inside a Fragment

Tags: android, static, fragment, custom-adapter

I am trying to populate a list view with a custom adapter, but I am getting
the following error "App.this cannot be referenced from a static context".

The problem is not "getActivity()" but the CustomAdapter itself being called from a static context. What is the correct way to do this?

```
public class App extends Activity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //
   }

   static public class PlanetFragment extends Fragment {
       ListView lv;
       String planet=null;

       public PlanetFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
       } 



       @Override
       public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

           lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), savedInstanceState, planet));

       }



       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
           lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
           }
        }
      }

   class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
   {

   //Some access to context and operations etc is done to populate the rows

   }
}
```

Comment: what is the scope of `CustomAdapter`?  Where is it declared?

Comment: Please post the actual stack trace.

Comment: which line is giving you the error

Comment: this line gives the error: lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), savedInstanceState, planet));